# `meteor create` "Errors prevented isopacket load"

Tags: meteor

Whenever I use `meteor create x` I get this same error. Uninstalled, reinstalled, still get the same error and I can't quite find someone else who is having the same issue. Mete

```
PS C:\Users\x\source\Meteor> meteor create todos
Errors prevented isopacket load:

While loading isopacket `combined`:

C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.10.2\mt-os.windows.x86_64\tools\fs\tools\fs\files.ts:1170:25:
sourcemapConsumer.destroy is not a function
at
C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.10.2\mt-os.windows.x86_64\tools\fs\tools\fs\files.ts:1170:25
at Function.time
<snip>


C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.10.2\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:218
      throw error;
      ^

Error: isopacket load failed?
    at loadIsopacketFromDisk (C:\tools\tool-env\isopackets.js:320:11)
    at C:\tools\tool-env\isopackets.js:113:9
    at loadIsopackage (C:\tools\tool-env\isopackets.js:104:21)
    at ProjectContext._buildResolver (C:\tools\project-context.js:817:34)
    <snip>
```

[Full error message](https://pastebin.com/uGhVukea), SO won't let me post it all here

Inside `C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.10.2\mt-os.windows.x86_64\tools\fs\` there is no folder `tools\fs\` and no `files.ts` - there is `files.js`. But I don't get why there's a line specified in a file that doesn't exist

[Showing missing directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ags2M.png)

Comment: Did this occur with previous Meteor versions than `1.10.2`?

Comment: I have tried this on 1.10.1 with the same issue. I have also tried this on my laptop and I get a different error for the same line in the second error https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/378081613331955712/709039955317620796/unknown.png